# css grid auto add rows based on the auto of text

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to figure out if what I am trying to achieve with css grid is even possible. I have "designed" a grid with a fixed row size of 100px. `grid-auto-rows: 100px` but if I add text that requires two or more rows, the rows collapse. I have a have to set the `grid-row: auto / span 2`.

Is there a way to make this automatic? So that css grid will make it span 1, 2 or 3 row etc. I tried using `grid-auto-flow: row` but sense that is the default value, that is not gonna do the trick?

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ozrmem) so you can go in and check it out.

Change the code from

```
.fixed-grid .blue {
  grid-row: auto/span 2;
}
```

to

```
.fixed-grid .blue {
  grid-row: auto/span 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is you are trying to achieve but you might want . A minimumum row height of 100px for each row but expand as required...is that right?

Comment: ...but you can't make a div span multiple rows *automatically*...but you can expand the row height based on content. This sounds like you're trying to achieve a masonry look and JS is the solution for that.

Comment: Sorry about not explaining very well. I basically want all the grid rows to stay at a fixed size 100px, no min or max - and not expand or shrink based on the its content. But rather just have the content itself take up another row.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that without JS.

Comment: Okay thanks. Perhaps you should write this as an answer, so I close this.